# Google Play App Signing upload.pem?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

I've developed and uploaded an android app to the Google Play Store, and I "accidentally" clicked the enable Google Play App Signing.. Now my app has been "stuck" at that stage for some hours now, and I'm suspecting the signed .apk (signed by my, by a jks I have on my machine) is not signed with the correct certificate..

Since I clicked enable to the Google Play App Signing, I got a "upload.pem" and a "deployment.pem", but I have no idea on what to do with these to certificates, and absolutely no idea on how to sign my .apk with these/one of these, since the info page only says that you need to use the upload to sign the .apk. (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)

So I'm wondering if anyone could help me with what to do, and how to sign the app correctly?..

Comment: It was the first apk you uploaded for that app?

Comment: Yes. So google has provided me with the upload.pem

Comment: I used the previous keystore to sign the second version of the app and it got uploaded successfully to Play Store. But it is getting signed with a different keystore in they Play Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to import upload.pem to keystore that you used to sign the APK previously, unless you are using a new keystore to sign the APK. Just sign it with your keystore and upload it to Play Store.

Comment: if i understand i can continue to use the keystore without problem.. IF i lose it i can generate a new keystore and import the upload.pem on the new keystore? so the problem happen only if i lost the keystore, right?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing/44103025#44103025) if you need help with the procedure

Comment: I know this, but I don't understand how I sign the .apk with the upload.pem file. When clicking the "Generate Signed APK" in Android Studio, this only allows me to use an existing .jks or create a new one. I can't find anywhere to use the .pem file..

Comment: How do I do this..? Just rename the .pem file?

EDIT: Because I've already tried to use just the .pem file as keystore, as the "key store path" in the Generate Signed APK wizard, but that just tells me that the keystore is in an invalid keystore format.

Comment: I've tried this, and then I'm getting this error: 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload.pem from store "/Users/kasperrt/Downloads/upload.pem": Invalid keystore format

Comment: Mmmm... let me search a bit if i can found anything. This topic is so new for everyone :D

Comment: @KasperRynning-Tønnesen have you successfully completed it? Btw i've updated the answer to point to the guide i've created to help other developer with the steps to perform

Comment: I got it working.

Since I've just accepted, and then uploaded my apk file, it uses the .jks thats "default" (that I've created) for when signing the file.

Answer (score 0):

**just add publish sha1 key in your api console**

*you have some publish upload sha1 key, md5, another type of hash key. just copy the sha 1 key and paste api console with app package name.*
**its work for me ,i hope this will help. thak you**