# How to enable Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, android-signing, android-app-signing

I think a lot of developers are trying to learn more about the new Google Play App Signing feature presented at Google I/O 2017.

The ability to store the keystore to sign the apps inside Google Play save you the effort to safely store the keystore and can help the system to optimize the APKs served to every device, based on hardware and OS characteristics.

You can read more about this topic in the official documentation here : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing.

With the following answer, i will explain a bit better the steps you need to follow to upload your original keystore and how to create the new upload keystore, which you will need to sign your APK from this point onwards.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

***Before proceeding watch this Android Developers video to understand the implications of your App Signing enrollment choice:
https://youtu.be/odv_1fxt9BI***

*This guide is oriented to developers who already have an application in the Play Store. If you are starting with a new app the process it's much easier and you can follow the guidelines of paragraph "New apps" from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB)*

**Prerequisites that 99% of developers already have** :

1. **Android Studio**
2. **JDK 8**  and after installation you need to setup an environment variable in your user space to simplify terminal commands. In Windows x64 you need to add this : `C:\Program Files\Java\{JDK_VERSION}\bin` to the `Path` environment variable. (If you don't know how to do this you can read my guide to [add a folder to the Windows 10 `Path` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho/44272417#44272417)).

**Step 0**: Open Google Play developer console, then go to *Release Management -> App Signing*.

[image]

Accept the App Signing TOS.

[image]

**Step 1**: Download PEPK Tool clicking the button identical to the image below

[image]

**Step 2**: Open a terminal and type:

> java -jar PATH_TO_PEPK --keystore=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE
> --alias=ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK --output=PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE --encryptionkey=GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY

Legend:

- *PATH_TO_PEPK* = Path to the pepk.jar you downloaded in **Step 1**, could be something like `C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\pepk.jar` for Windows users.
- *PATH_TO_KEYSTORE* = Path to keystore which you use to sign your release APK. Could be a file of type *.keystore or *.jks or without extension. Something like `C:\Android\mykeystore` or `C:\Android\mykeystore.keystore` etc...
- *ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK* = The name of the alias you use to sign the release APK.
- *PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE* = The path of the output file with .pem extension, something like `C:\Android\private_key.pem`
- *GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY* = This encryption key should be always the same. You can find it in the App Signing page, copy and paste it. Should be in this form: `eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a`

Example:

> java -jar "C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\pepk.jar" --keystore="C:\Android\mykeystore"
> --alias=myalias --output="C:\Android\private_key.pem" --encryptionkey=eb10fe8f7c7c9df715022017b00c6471f8ba8170b13049a11e6c09ffe3056a104a3bbe4ac5a955f4ba4fe93fc8cef27558a3eb9d2a529a2092761fb833b656cd48b9de6a

Press Enter and you will need to provide in order:

1. The keystore password
2. The alias password

If everything has gone OK, you now will have a file in PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE folder called `private_key.pem`.

**Step 3**: Upload the private_key.pem file clicking the button identical to the image below

[image]

**Step 4**: Create a new keystore file using Android Studio.

> YOU WILL NEED THIS KEYSTORE IN THE FUTURE TO SIGN THE NEXT RELEASES OF
> YOUR APP, DON'T FORGET THE PASSWORDS

Open one of your Android projects (choose one at random). Go to *Build* -> *Generate Signed APK* and press *Create new*.

[image]

Now you should fill the required fields.

> Key store path represent the new keystore you will create, choose a folder and a name using the 3 dots icon on the right, i choosed `C:\Android\upload_key.jks` (.jks extension will be added automatically)

> NOTE: I used `upload` as the new alias name but if you previously used the same keystore with different aliases to sign different apps, you should choose the same aliases name you had previously in the original keystore.

[image]

Press OK when finished, and now you will have a new `upload_key.jks` keystore. You can close Android Studio now.

**Step 5**: We need to extract the upload certificate from the newly created `upload_key.jks` keystore.
Open a terminal and type:

> keytool -export -rfc -keystore UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_PATH -alias UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
> -file PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE

Legend:

- *UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_PATH* = The path of the upload keystore you just created. In this case was `C:\Android\upload_key.jks`.
- *UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_ALIAS* = The new alias associated with the upload keystore. In this case was `upload`.
- *PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE* = The path to the output file with .pem extension. Something like `C:\Android\upload_key_public_certificate.pem`.

Example:

> keytool -export -rfc -keystore "C:\Android\upload_key.jks" -alias upload -file "C:\Android\upload_key_public_certificate.pem"

Press Enter and you will need to provide the keystore password.

Now if everything has gone OK, you will have a file in the folder PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE called `upload_key_public_certificate.pem`.

**Step 6**: Upload the `upload_key_public_certificate.pem` file clicking the button identical to the image below

[image]

**Step 7**: Click *ENROLL* button at the end of the App Signing page.

[image]

Now every new release APK must be signed with the `upload_key.jks` keystore and aliases created in **Step 4**, prior to be uploaded in the Google Play Developer console.

More Resources:

- [Google documentation on Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB)
- [Form to request the reset of your upload keystore if you lose it](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs)

### **Q&A**

Q: When i upload the APK signed with the new upload_key keystore, Google Play show an error like : *You uploaded an unsigned APK. You need to create a signed APK*.

A: Check to sign the APK with both signatures (V1 and V2) while building the release APK. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43088600/2910520) for more details.

### **UPDATED**

The step 4,5,6 are to create upload key which is optional for existing apps

"Upload key (optional for existing apps): A new key you generate during your enrollment in the program. You will use the upload key to sign all future APKs prior to uploading them to the Play Console."
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: Your walkthrough is super helpful! They should put it on the official website lol

The pathnames for your examples are missing " _ " quotes which will throw an error on W10 Console

Comment: The quotes are needed only if you have at least one space inside your paths, but this is the way every console command works. So you have to use the quotes if your path is: `"C:\My Path\MyName"` but not if the path is `C:\MyPath\MyName`. Btw thank you :)

Comment: Finally worked but you should create new jsk (you canot use the old one)or google play will refuse rolling, thank you very much

Comment: @layth Creating the new keystore is the `Step 4` of the guide :D

Comment: It was not clear from the description but in the step where youre making the new keystore you need to select the last used GooglePlay keystore and enter its password. Also the alias cant be the same as the one used by those old keystores ... so I added "app" to the end :)

Comment: @NukeouT No, you don't need the old keystore and the password in Step 4. You simply have to click on `Create New`, and the new keystore prompt will appear. I've updated the documentation to make this step a bit clearer even if i think it was already

Comment: I did that but when I got your new keystore dialog its keystore path and password fields were blank so I pointed them at the old keystore and entered its old password - btw currently stuck on "keytool -export -rfc -keystore UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_PATH -alias UPLOAD_KEYSTORE_ALIAS -file PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE" keeps complaining that it does not know what keytool means. I tried adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\keytool.exe" but that did not work, possibly because I dont know where to put it in exactly..

Comment: You have to put it in the Windows `Path` environment variable (i think i will create a guide on this too, because a lot of guide on the net are outdated)

Comment: Ok. Ty ill stay up and wait for it. Btw the new key worked once I typed in your file name + .jks and repeated the same new password 4 times

Comment: I've updated all the documentation, now i added some words on how to let the system create the upload_key.jks. Thank you for pointing this out, now the Step 4 should be easier for everyone. I will make the guide on how to add the JDK to Path EV for Windows 10 tonight when i go home

Comment: @NukeouT [i've create the guide to add a folder to the Windows 10 `Path` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/2910520) let me know if this works for you or if you encounter any problems (obviously you need to substitute the example folder with the `bin` folder of your JDK)

Comment: I set the variable name as keytool and the variable value as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\keytool.exe but it still says on execution it does not know what keytool is :(

Comment: I said in the guide on how to configure the environment variable that you should add the folder and not the specific tool. So remove keytool.exe from the path. (Keytool is a Java utility, it's extension is .jar not .exe)

Comment: It looks like Google changed the procedure, because I can't find PEPK Tool anymore.

Comment: @AndreaMotto i've just re-checked the procedure now with another developer account not already subscribed to the Google App Signing and downloading the PEPK Tool it's the first Step to perform yet. I suggest you to double check everything

Comment: @MatPag you're right. I have created a new app, that's why the procedure is different. I can find PEPK Tool in my old app.

Comment: @AndreaMotto The new apps need to follow the link i added on the first lines of the answer ;)

Comment: Also you may have problem with your PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE 
I recommend you to use 
1. " " example "D:\My_key.pem" 
2. and also don't try do it on C:\ (where you have windows). When i try on C i always get an error(maybe need permisions). Than i tried to do it with quotes and disc E and it work fine.

Comment: @JacktheRipper It works fine on C:\ too, Windows is inside the C:\Windows folder and not in C:\ root folder. For the quotes read the second comment

Comment: I'm writting a new app, I opt for google signin, they deliver two pem certificates. I created a local jks ans signed my app and upload. Obviously, they rejected saying the fingerprints don't match. But I see no way to register or download a "upload key". What am I missing?

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes read the first 3 lines of the guide. For new apps the steps are different

Comment: I read it. Maybe I'm now figured out the key thing: the upload key of an app will be the key used to sign the first apk uploaded? Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walkthrough! I have multiple apps signed with the same key. Some of the apps are in one account, and the rest in a different one. Can I enable this only for one of the app in an account? Will I still be able to update the rest of the apps as usual?

Comment: @akbas Yes, this is enabled per app not per account ;)

Comment: @MatPag i can no longer find the link to pepk tool, has the documentation changed? All i see in in App Signing screen is bunch of certificates

Comment: @MatPag Might be a stupid question, but once Google are managing the App signing key, can I delete it? I'm guessing it's redundant as Google are now signing all future apps and I will only be signing with an upload key

Comment: @sam9046 "theorically" you could delete the signing key after you have been enrolled with the Google App signing. Practically. Practically i don't have the right answer for this :D

Comment: @MatPag  pepk tool is missing for new apps. Any official updates?

Comment: @SebinBenjamin You don't need the PEPK tool for new apps. Read the first 3 lines of this guide please.

Comment: @MatPag sorry..missed it.

Comment: In case anybody gets an error saying `Error: Could not find or load main class`, that just means you forgot to add `-jar` in your command. It's an easy fix, but it wasn't until I read MattPag's thorough explanation that I noticed my error.

Comment: Why my "APP SIGNING PRIVATE KEY" is disabled??

Comment: the account owner needs to accept the terms and conditions. See above step one in this answer. Once the terms and conditions are accepted APP SIGNING PRIVATE KEY will be enabled to upload.

Comment: after entering both passwords its show error like - error:F\foldername

Comment: Cant find this pepk file anywhere.

Comment: So, if Google App Signing is enabled, you don't need the keystore to update the app, right?

Comment: Great job about the Walkthrough, it's really simple and straight forward. Thank you. I've a question;

"Is it still possible to sign the apk with the original keystore(Which has been used before Google App Signing) after applying to Google App Signing?"

Comment: @Aydinozkan thank you no you can't sign the apk with the old keystore

Comment: @MatPag I was previously signing my APK with a p12 file. After activating Google App Signing I am still able to sign the APK with the previous p12 and I can upload it to Google Play Console as a release version.

Comment: @Aydinozkan Are you sure you completed the Google app Signing process? That's really strange

Comment: @MatPag yes I did, I'm sure because I'm able to see the fingerprints of both App Signing and Upload Certificates and I can sign my apk with the newly created Upload keystore and upload it to Google Play Console. I've contacted Google Play Customer Service about this issue, I will comment again at this post if we achieve any progress.

Comment: @MatPag I've contacted Google about the issue. They have remarked that, there is no problem with signing the APK both with the old p12 certificate or with the newly created upload keystore. Both will be applicable to sign the APK.

Comment: Can someone please clarify, I read that if you lose your signingkey/keystore or forget it's password you can no longer update the app, you were signing, is this no longer true???

Comment: This Doc should get more and more up-votes. I am not able to find GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY in App Signing Page

Comment: I've just uploaded the old jks encrypted. And that's it. No new jks creation, and I have no idea what the upload key means now. I'm try to upload a new apk, signed like before this process and it's works fine. I'm afraid when I really need to send a new apk to the store and get blocked.

Comment: It seems step 4,5,6 are optional, I can enroll after step 3 and enable to upload aab file just fine. Just use the old key store to sign app as usual.

Comment: @thanhbinh84 thanks for the edit. They changed something with the latest updates. I'll try to update the tutorial accordingly when i have time :)

Comment: @MatPag your tutorial is still valid, just want to add more info that the second key store is optional and called upload key. Thanks for the tutorial, it is much clearer than google guide. :D

Comment: If you created the Keystore using Visual Studio Xamarin the keystore password and the alias password are the same. I just find out by trial and error.

Comment: you have fantastic fully complete answer,But in my case i need to know how to generate Facebook key hash from already published App with app signing certificate having only the deployment_cert.der file ,thank you in advance.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to do perform the private key Opt-In/Upload with Google Developer Publisher API?  Haven't found anything yet...

Comment: I have followed the same steps and able to upload the app in the internal testing but problem is that PlayStore shows me updated version but instead of Update it shows me Open button. So I can't able to update my app in internal testing.

Answer (score 53):

There is a much simpler solution that will take a minute.

1. In google play console, select **Release management** -> **App signing**
2. Choose the first option, the one with Generate encrypted private key with Android Studio (or something like that; I cannot turn back to see that page anymore)
3. In Android Studio generate your Android App Bundle (.aab file) from **Build** -> **Generate Signed Bundle / APK...**, choose **Android App Bundle** option and don't forget to check **Export Encrypted key (needed to enroll your app Google Play App signing)** option. If you do not have a keystore generated, generate one ad-hoc.
4. Now the "tricky" part. After the .aab is generated, Android Studio will pop up a notification in the bottom right corner containing a path to the location where the .aab file is saved. In the same notification, if you will expand it you will find another link to the path where the private key was saved (called **private_key.pepk**). If you miss this notification, don't worry, just open **Event Log** window by clicking the **Event Log** button on the bottom right side and you will find the same info. Open that location.For me was C:\Users\yourUser\.android

[image]

5. Go back in browser and press APP SIGNING PRIVATE KEY button and browse to the private key location on your computer.

Done!

Now you are able to upload your release that you generated earlier :)
Good luck!

Comment: I am not getting this option Export Encrypted key (needed to enroll your app Google Play App signing) option.

Comment: I would really appreciate a fuller explanation of point 5 - I don't see this button, where is it, perhaps the layout has changed on recent updates?

Comment: ok nice now i want to curious about that on the next update what to do ?? like is we need .pepk key again or we have to sign the version 2 using same key or the new private .pepk key pls help

Comment: For now, there is no such button in the Google Play Console... They have "App integrity" menu instead, without an option to upload new key..

Answer (score 32):

While Migrating Android application package file (APK) to Android App Bundle (AAB), publishing app into Play Store i faced this issue and got resolved like this below...

When building `.aab` file you get prompted for the location to store key export path as below:

[image]
    [image]
In second image you find Encrypted key export path Location where our .pepk will store in the specific folder while generating .aab file.

Once you log in to the Google Play Console with play store credential:
select your project from left side choose App Signing option Release Management>>App Signing
 [image]

you will find the Google App Signing Certification window ACCEPT it.

After that you will find three radio button select 
**

> Upload a key exported from Android Studio radio button

**, it will expand you
 APP SIGNING PRIVATE KEY button as below

[image]

click on the button and choose the `.pepk` file (We Stored while generating `.aab` file as above)

Read the all other option and submit.

Once Successfully you can go back to app release and browse the .aab file and complete RollOut...

@Ambilpura

Comment: ok nice now i want to curious about that on the next update what to do ?? like is we need .pepk key again or we have to sign the version 2 using same key or the new private .pepk key pls help

Comment: As per my understanding, no need to create for next time, u can use old .pepk key....

Comment: How do you use the .pepk for an update? I successfully used google app signing when uploading my app, but now im trying to push an update and don't know how @AmbilpuraSunilKumar

Comment: Same here. I just upload the abb to the play store and completely ignore the .pepk file. It would be nice to know what exactly it is good for and what to do when updating the app.

Comment: This newer answer should be pushed up to the top. It is the simplest way to migrate an existing app to the App Bundle.

Answer (score 9):

for Updated Google Console  go to inside Setup and open App integrity. and upload your key here. you will be good to go.

[image: screen shot for updated google console]

Comment: how about incorporating this into the appropriate original answer OR is this a replacement?

Comment: A word of caution - you need to be the account owner to agree to the terms, so if you're working with another company, you'll need to get them the private key to perform the upload and save the file, then they can agree to the terms.

Answer (score 7):

I had to do following:

1. Create an app in google play console
   [image]

2.Go to **App releases -> Manage production -> Create release**

3.Click continue on Google Play App Signing
[image]

4.Create upload certificate by running "keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\path\to\cert.keystore -alias uploadKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000"

5.Sign your apk with generated certificate (c:\path\to\cert.keystore)

6.Upload signed apk in **App releases -> Manage production -> Edit release**

7.By uploading apk, certificate generated in step 4 has been added to **App Signing certificates** and became your signing cert for all future builds.

Comment: I did exactly this but the google signin from my app does not work if I install the app via the Google Play Store. _*But*_ if I download the apk from the release management page and install it manually into my emulator / device, it works. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

When you use **Fabric** for public beta releases (signed with prod config), **DON'T USE** Google Play App Signing.
You will must after build two signed apks!

When you distribute to more play stores (samsung, amazon, xiaomi, ...) you will must again build two signed apks.

So be really carefull with Google Play App Signing.

**It's not possible to revert it :/** and Google Play did not after accept apks signed with production key. After enable Google Play App Signing only upload key is accepted...

It really complicate CI distribution...

Next issues with upgrade: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69285256

Comment: Bold capital `DON'T USE` type of comments is dangerous. Can you explain the issue and recommended solution in detail? Isn't there a solution at all? Is it so hard to sign an APK twice for Fabric?

Comment: I'ts not so hard to sign APK twice, but as I describe, you must build two (or more) APKs which are not identical (so you are testing on Fabric Beta different file than which will be published to Play Store). It loose point of testing production build on beta testers... you are testing another file :). It's just a warning for people which have some complex CI/CD that they must chnage it...

Comment: Note that Google Play now accepts APKs signed with the production key even after enrolling in App signing.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following :

```
"CREATE APPLICATION" having the same name which you want to upload before.
Click create.
After creation of the app now click on the "App releases"
Click on the "MANAGE PRODUCTION"
Click on the "CREATE RELEASE"
Here you see "Google Play App Signing" dialog.
Just click on the "OPT-OUT" button.
It will ask you to confirm it. Just click on the "confirm" button
```

Comment: After this can I able to test in app purchase and play services as like before? Did you get any experience regarding this?
Because even I don't like to do any heavy steps.

Comment: Not really an appropriate answer for "How to **Enable** Google Play App Signing"...