# How to disable App Signing from Google Play Console

Tags: google-play, android-app-signing

How can I disable App Signing from Google Play Console for all the apps already uploaded on Play store and for new apps?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't disable App Signing after being activated as you can read in the image below:

[image]

Here you can find the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), but the section of the screenshot has been removed. I will leave it here because it's still valid.

If you are stucked with it, you can follow the guide i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)

Comment: it's worth mentioning that the opt-in is permanent FOR THE APP, not the account. If you haven't published the app yet, you can just create a new one

Comment: Hi MatPag my app has published in beta mode , how can i disable google app signing , should i remove my app and create a another app or ??

Comment: @miladsalimi yes, this is the best approach

Comment: MatPag,After i remove it and create new one , the package name and apps name are same dont we have restriction about it?

Comment: If you remove the app the package name will be available again (i don't think you should have problems, and if there are problems play store will sure warn you)

Comment: Thank you MatPag

Comment: I can't find this section anymore. The docs don't mention anything about it being permanent. It still seems to be implied and there is no way back, but its no longer explicit.

Comment: @O'Rooney yeah they removed it. I've updated the answer, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: When creating the first release, I click `Change app signing key`, `use a different key`, but I only have the options to upload a private key to google or use the google key. Is there a way I can use a key on my private HSM (without publishing it to google)?

Answer (score 21):

Quoting the @MatPag you can't disable the app signing after activating it from Google Play Console. Here is the quick way to resolve this issue.

1. "CREATE APPLICATION" having the same name which you want to upload before.
2. Click create.
3. After creation of the app now click on the "App releases"
4. Click on the "MANAGE PRODUCTION"
5. Click on the "CREATE RELEASE"
6. Here you see "Google Play App Signing" dialog.
7. Just click on the "OPT-OUT" button.
8. It will ask you to confirm it. Just click on the "confirm" button.

You are ready to Drop your APK file with your signing key. Just give it a try.

Comment: This works fine if the app has not being published yet.
Thank you!

Comment: It does not work for me. Is this still working in 2023? I only have the option to upload a private key instead of letting goolge create one, but I want to keep my private key private.

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't published yet, you can delete the app and then recreate it, and opt out of the google play app signing.

Comment: so smart really!

Answer (score 3):

If Anyone is looking here because FIREBASE requires the new SHA1 fingerprint you can find it in the APP SIGNING screen and add it to your app for notification or authentication ....[image]

We don't even have to change the JSON file that you have to include in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your app, since it is still in the draft mode, and you can restart again, this time choose to opt-out even though it is recommended.