# Android Unable to Upload release APK App Signing issue

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

I am uploading new Android Application to Play store. While uploading Release APK i am facing following error. Why its asking me to sign my application with new key?[image]

> Upload failed  You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that
>   is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are
>   enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key
>   before you upload it.

Please help

Comment: You enrolled your app for App Signing, this should be the steps you need to create the new upload keystore if you already didn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing

Comment: can i roll it back ? and upload that without doing this ?

Comment: No, there is now way to go back as i stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210605/2910520). Your only choice is to follow all the steps until the end