# android signing tool PEPK lnk for download

Tags: android, apk, signing, apktool

is there any link to download the PEPK tool? Currently searching for it but unable to find it out. I searched a lot, as I am new, I am little bit confused as well not able to find any secure source to download it

Comment: You get it from Google Play. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When you opt in to use Google Play App Signing, you export and encrypt your app signing key using the **Play Encrypt Private Key tool provided by Google Play**, and then upload it to Google's infrastructure

[App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

You download it from the app signing dashboard of Google Play

[How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)

Comment: Thank you so much for your support

Answer (score 5):

Download link: https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar

I don't know why Google doesn't make the download link available in the development documentation, instead you have to enter to the Google Play Console, and act like you are going to opt-in to the signing process to see the link above:

[image]