# Android studio 3.0 does not generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

After updating android studio to version 3.0 (windows), I am unable to generate a signed APK.

[image]

When build has completed, i get the message:

[image]

Clicking "Locate" brings me to the APP folder, but there is no APK to be found.

What has been changed ?

Comment: Whats ur device, Windows, mac, linux? I just updated it is working fine

Comment: Make sure your folder item VISIBLE or not

Comment: @NirajSanghani "C:\apps\app" does this path seems like Linux?

Comment: Are you able to access this folder and also do you have write permission?

Comment: Did you try using gradlew from console to generate release build e.g. gradlew.bat assembleRelease from your project root folder

Comment: just trying to help, chill out, sorry to miss that

Comment: I get the same issue in Linux

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since Android Studio 3.0 update, the apk generated will be in

```
{project-folder}/app/release/app-release.apk
```

Also 1 more file is generated Output.json which holds the apk generation details.

Sample:

```
[  
   {  
      "outputType":{  
         "type":"APK"
      },
      "apkInfo":{  
         "type":"MAIN",
         "splits":[  

         ],
         "versionCode":1
      },
      "path":"app-debug.apk",
      "properties":{  
         "packageId":"njscommunity.xxxxx",
         "split":"",
         "minSdkVersion":"19"
      }
   }
]
```

All depends on Gradle build, so at the end it all depends on Gradle version you build with. i.e. Gradle Android plugin for Android Studio.

Comment: This only holds true if you run a release build via run, but if you manually generate release build then it gets generated where the location is picked

Comment: did u check atleast, i just did that manually, yet it went to that folder

Comment: yeas so whereever u build there will be /release/app-release.apk

Comment: also try using other than C drive, It does give Access issues in some constraints

Comment: did u  find ur solution?

Comment: Yes, but the OP is manually generating Signed APK via Build > Generate Signed APK menu

Comment: I did it the same way, will just do that.

Comment: It would seem that a restart of android studio was required, and signed apks are now placed in /app/release/... Thanks

Comment: This isn't working for me. I am having the same issue as OP, but there is no /app/release folder. There is only /app which is where it normally generates to, but there is no "release" folder. Simply nothing seems to be generating.

Comment: mine was actually in {project_folder}/{module_name}/production/release

Comment: gradle build, so at the end it all depends on gradle version u build with. i.e. gradle android plugin for android studio

Comment: Android Studio used to create an app-release.apk file in the folder you selected. Now, it generates a folder called release, then puts it in there. Confusingly, when you click 'locate' in the finished box it still brings you to the folder you selected, not to the release folder it generated... Took me half an hour to figure it out...

Comment: Downvote, because it didn't solve OP's (and my) problem. @Sahil Kapoor's helped me. 
In my eyes it is inconsistent that clicking on "locate" in balloon message leads to the directory that is chosen and not the directory where apk is. Where can I file a bug?

Comment: Issue with Android studio when trying to tap locate it takes you to the old location and not the correct one mentioned in the answer +1.

Comment: Android Studio 3 created app/release/release/app.aab So there is no app-release.apk ? There is no hidden files in there.Can anyone help?

Comment: Ok. Turned out app.aab new sort of .apk of Android Studio 3

Answer (score 29):

**Android Studio 3.0** Now creates a **"release"** folder inside the specified destination folder and places the release apk inside that.

**{APK Destination Folder}\release\app-release.apk**

OR as mentioned by @velis

**{APK Destination Folder} \ {flavor} \ {variant} \ {apkname}.apk**

For Example:-
In your case: **C:\apps\app\release\app-release.apk**

Comment: This is really close, but 'variant' is actually a combination of 'flavor' and 'build type'. So if you have two flavors dev and production, and two build type debug and release then you have four possibles and the folders will be `{APK Destination Folder}\{Flavor}\{BuildType}\{apkname}.apk`

Comment: It took me hours to figure out that it was located inside the {flavor} folder.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I found apk file in folder `{specified_destination}/{flavor_name}/release folder`

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact issue after upgrading to Android studio 3.0 (windows)

After spending HOURS looking for the solution,
I find out that, **that simple action solved it for me:**

changing the destination path apk to different path.
(for me to C:) just solved it

[image: Generate Signed APK dialog]

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. After a few hours downgrading

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

solved the issue in the build.gradle file.

Comment: Gradle 3.0.0 is a very important release with many changes. Downgrading is not a solution.

Comment: I am aware. But if you need an urgent release to the market, I prefer to sign properly my APK. Yo can always work with gradle 3.0.0 and change it only to produce release.

Comment: In fact, I prefer to sign an APK, that after I updated to gradle 3.0.0 I cannot. For me it is valid, so if 3.0.0 is not working for all the people, are you trying to say that the solurion is updating to 3.0.0 and not signing any APK?? Thanks for your negative feedback, btw

Comment: Upvoted this because it worked for me in the short term. But I can understand that this is a not very satisfying workaround.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Now the right answer is the one proposed by Sahil Kopoor, but when I answered it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

[Sahil Kapoor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115496/1760858) was almost on mark:

The generated file's path is your specified destination folder + `{flavor}/{variant}/`

**{destination} / {flavor} / {variant} / {apkname}.apk**

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that Android Studio 3.0 will make it an .aab file which is an app bundle file.  This enables you to have the code signing in google play, so you don't have to have the key locally.  There is an answer here on how to do that. [How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)  Seems to be a step in the right direction, even if it is not very clear when actually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all is correct but android studio is not generated the APK and i'm not getting an error message.

Previously i was update my package name `com.test.package` >  `com.final.name.package` using refactor all works fine even create an not signed APK.

Finally i can see that my applicationId inside the gradle has the old package name, when change it for the new package name the signed APK is generated without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for me this thing works :

1. Check the folder in which the apk is going to generated. Normally it will be the Android Studio Project > app > release
2. If this folder is having "app-release.apk" then remove the same and try to regenerate the signed apk.