# After Android Studio 3.1.1 update, the 'locate' link does not open generated APK folder

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.1

**UPDATE: The problem came after Android 3.1.1 update.**

After APK generation process is completed, Android Studio (Windows OS) propose a popup to locate or analyze the APK.

[image]

Unfortunately if I click on **locate**, nothing is happening.

**UPDATE**

In the APK Generetion Dialog I specify the destination path, a folder on my pc:

[image]

And in some projects I use a bounche of gradle lines to rename the APK:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == BuilderConstants.RELEASE) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def padVersionCode = variant.versionCode.toString();
            padVersionCode = padVersionCode.padLeft(5, '0')
            def newApkName = "${output.baseName}_${padVersionCode}-${variant.versionName}"
            newApkName = newApkName + ".apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
        }
    }
}
```

I see the APK renamed and place in th expected folder, the locate link is the only dat does not work.

Comment: you can find it out inside your app/build/output/release

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you clic on locate inside the Event Log window ? (we can see it on the bottom right on your image)

Comment: @RajSuvariya I've a complex build routine that saves APK in a special folder, your answer does not focus on the issue.

Comment: @xiaomi Yes, same problem from the Event Log window.

Comment: @RajSuvariya thanks anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio 3.0 does not generate signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949719/android-studio-3-0-does-not-generate-signed-apk)

Comment: @Seraphim's Let me know if that other question doesn't solve this at all, but I suspect it's the same issue, different symptom.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Problems cames after Android Studio 3.1.1 update (in 3.0 everything were fine), and is not a duplicate issue of a previous question.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I edited the question, more details now.

Comment: This bug last since I've started working on Mac, and there is like nobody about to fix it

Answer (score 7):

> Unfortunately if I click on locate, nothing is happening.

This to me looks like a bug in **Android Studio**.

In your case if you see the Android Studio logs (Help->Show Log in Explorer), you will see something like:

```
INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - not a directory: T:\COMPILED_APK\release
```

which means that you don't have a folder called called **release** inside **COMPILED_APK** folder.

So if you really want it this way then:

1. First create a folder called **release** inside **COMPILED_APK** folder.
2. Generate the apk.
3. Now when you click on locate, it will open up the release folder but nothing will be inside the folder.
4. To find your apk you have to navigate to `T:\COMPILED_APK\e\release`

This is weird, but this is how it works.

Comment: The message I see in the Android Studio log files is: 
"ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - not a directory: C:\<project directory>\app\debug". Adding the debug directory fixed it.