# How build apk file in android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk

I'm new in android studio . I wrote an application and this run on gent motion successfully , gent motion android version is 4.1., then I want to get apk file , but this don't work . I go `build>generate...` then keystore is build but apk file don't.

And I go `build>buildbundles>apks...` but too don't build apk file. I find one apk file in my project folder in:

`project>res>apk >apk_realese.apk`

and send this to my phone but don't install.

My phone android version is 7.1, and my project android version is 4. 
I don't know what do.

Please help.

Comment: If you want to build NOT signed `apk` (so just `.apk` you can use on your own without publishing it to store) try Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s) and after a while the alert will pop. Click "Locate" and you will be taken to the folder containing `.apk`.

Comment: I do this and say successful , but the apk file is not in the locate .

Answer (score 2):

In menu go to Build-> Build Bundles/APK ->Build APK .It will build your apk file.Once successfully finished, dialog will appear at bottom and just click locate it will move to the debug folder and you can get the apk file.It will install in all mobiles.

If you dont see apk file in that folder just follow the instructions in this link.

[After Android Studio 3.1.1 update, the 'locate' link does not open generated APK folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923569/after-android-studio-3-1-1-update-the-locate-link-does-not-open-generated-apk)

refer this too:

[Apk location in New Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio/22347103)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have successfully build your project then apk file will be stored in your `project/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/` folder.

Comment: apk_realese.apk i find this . but this file don't install in my phone . my phone android is 7.1 , and android in genymotion is 4.1 , and android in project is 4