# In my Google Play Account , App Signin Private Key Button is Disabled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-keystore, google-play-console

I am trying to generate SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for signed apk but its not working for me, the button is still disabled , i want to enabled the button..

[image: App Sign in Tab's Screen Shot]

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103025/7505436

Answer (score 2):

Manage your app signing keys . Please check the [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB)

Enable google play app signing keys check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing) for detail answer

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Actually i already generate .pem file and i am trying to upload that file but here the button is disabled . How do i enable that button ? @Janmejoy

Comment: @KevalShukla Please check this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423