# Cannot update release APK using Google Play app signing upload certificate (with original keystore)

Tags: android-studio, apk, keytool, android-keystore, google-play-console

I was trying to update a release on Google Play. Upon uploading my signed APK, I received this error message in the Google Play Console:

> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: *(SHA1 hash redacted)* ]
>
> and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: *(Mismatched SHA1 hash redacted)* ]

I have tried many different methods for signing my APK (original keystore, different password combinations, new keystores, different key combinations, etc.) but none have succeeded.

I am fairly confident that the keystore is the original keystore as I had it backed up on an external drive, and the update date on both versions of the file are approx 30 mins before the original release (which is when I generated the first signed APK).

Since I used Google Play app signing (and the expected SHA1 hash is the same as the Upload Certificate SHA1 hash in 'App Signing' tab on my Play Console) I assumed that I would need to import the cert into the keystore I used to upload the original release APK.

Here are my results, which I have repeatedly been checking for some time now to ensure that they were not caused by simple typo (redacted parts are grouped into colors by value, I can post most of them if necessary):

[image: Cannot update release APK using Google Play app signing upload certificate (with original keystore)]

Please note that the `keystorePass` and the actual `keyPass` were specified as different passes, so using the `keystorePass` for both returns a "Cannot recover key" UnrecoverableKeyException, while using `keyPass` for the key gives a general exception "Public keys in reply and keystore don't match."

Some of my research turned up that if the `keystorePass` and `keyPass` are not identical, then this issue will arise. The proposed solution was to use keytool to change the `keyPass` to be identical to the `keystorePass`, but after what I assume is a successful keytool keypasswd change, I still getting the exception "Public keys in reply and keystore don't match." Using the old `keyPass` returns the expected incorrect password exception. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Cannot update release APK using Google Play app signing upload certificate (with original keystore)]

For troubleshooting purposes, I tried adding the certificate directly to the keystore. That was a success using the `keystorePass` and gave me the expected SHA1 hash of the `uploade_cert.der` file from Google Play app signing:

[image: Cannot update release APK using Google Play app signing upload certificate (with original keystore)]

I also tried creating a new keystore (as well as new keys in both the original and new keystores with the same password), but trying to generate a signed APK using Android Studio with the new keystore after a successful keytool upload certificate import, I received this Android Studio error: "trusted certificate entries are not password-protected"

I have tried all of these steps with original and new infos in my gradle app file ( `signingConfigs{release{keyAlias, keyPassword, storeFile, storePassword}}` ) but no luck. Would love to get my app updated, and any tips or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing passwords for the key alias to match the keystore works fine, but upon trying to access the keystore in anyway the keystore password fails with "Public keys in reply and keystore do not match" -- not the usual incorrect pass error of "Keystore was tampered with, or the password was incorrect". In addition, trying to change the key alias password again to the same pass as the keystore allows the keystore pass to pass verification, but gives an error when entering it as the key pass: "Passwords must differ", which means it really is the same and correct key! wtf? :P

Comment: I checked by listing the keys in the keystore, and it accepted the keystore pass no problem even though it won't accept it for the importcert keytool command.

Comment: I also checked the keytool list of the key alias itself specifically, and that command worked fine with the password as well. So why can't I import the cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to try the follow procedure:

1. Encrypt your private key (yourKeyStore.jks) using the PEPK tool (available on your Google console) used for signing the first version of the APK.
2. Generate a new key (ex. apk-upload) and then extract the certificate from your created key in a upload-key.pem.
3. Upload the upload-key.pem to your Google Account.
4. Sign your release APK with your new key (apk-upload).

You will find the different commands and more details in this article:

https://medium.com/mindorks/securing-and-optimizing-your-app-with-google-play-app-signing-24a3658fd319

**EDIT:** (from comments) I think that if you had already enrolled Google App Signings, you have to contact Google support to gives you the ability to upload new private key or to get you old private key... the options given when you subscribe to Google App Signings, and I think that it's not possible to resign your application with the old way if you had already enrolled Google App Signing.

(*Asker's Edit*: Don't use a different password for your keystore as you do the original key alias itself. Make sure that both keystorePass and keyPass are an exact match. If you already uploaded your keystore/key with different passes, then follow the steps on the Google Support page to reset your keystore with App Signing.)

Comment: When I go to the Google Play Console and click "App Signing", it only shows me the App Signing cert and the Upload cert hashes. There is nothing on the PEPK tool or uploading PEM files. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7eIzi)

Comment: You should enable Google app signing : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103025/8126192

Comment: As I said above, the only options in the "App Signing" section of Google Play Console are the ones in the screenshot. Here is a direct link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/7eIzi

I presume this means I have already been opted into the App Signing service, however, I did not ever download PEPK tools or upload a PEM cert. As verified in the screenshot, there is a box at the top which says "Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app."

Comment: I think that if you had already enrolled Google App Signings, you have to contact Google support to gives you the ability to upload new private key or to get you old private key.

https://i1.wp.com/blog.fossasia.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/screenshot_20170822_204951-750x586.png?resize=660%2C516

You can see in this link above, the options given when you subscribe to Google App Signings, and I think that it's not possible to resign your application with the old way if you had already enrolled Google App Signings. Thanks

Comment: I have already contact Google Play Console about the issue. The reply was not relevant to the question, unfortunately, and I am still waiting for a relevant response from their support team. They also assumed that I was trying to sign my APK the old way. If I am enrolled in App Signing, as the page says I am, should I expect to see the PEPK Tool download button, as well as the other buttons, on the App Signing page? As I said, all I see are the key hashes -- and I never uploaded anything to App Signing in the first place!

Comment: Google App Signing will be enabled and Google will use an arbitrary key as private key for the app and the first app you upload will get its key registered as the upload key.

Here are the steps I followed for a new app:

  1- Download upload certificat and add it to your original keystore (use the same alias, it should tell you to replace existing certificat, say yes):

keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore <keystorefile>

2- Sign your Apk as you did it the first time, upload you signed apk and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164519/discussion-between-randall-arms-and-sparow199).

Comment: @RandallArmsJr. did you ever resolve this.  I think I'm having the same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449970/how-do-i-resolve-the-issue-where-subsequent-apk-upload-certificate-differs-from

Comment: @D.Hodges: Yes, the parent answer to these comments is the accepted answer, and I have added my own edits to make it clear what worked for me. Here is a summary of what worked: 
1. Encrypt your private key (yourKeyStore.jks) using the PEPK tool (available on your Google console) used for signing the first version of the APK.
2. Generate a new key (ex. apk-upload) and then extract the certificate from your created key in a upload-key.pem.
3. Upload the upload-key.pem to your Google Account.
4. Sign your release APK with your new key (apk-upload).
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I went to my backup folder with the Keystore I had recorded in my bundle, downloaded it and re-added it to app and that worked, no Google App signing malarkey required :)