# How do I resolve the issue where subsequent .apk upload certificate differs from the original

Tags: android, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore, google-developers-console

I'm trying to upload a new .apk file to Open Testing in the Google Play Developer Console and I'm getting this error:

```
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
    SHA1: key:key:key
    and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded has fingerprint:
    SHA1: a:diff:key
    Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS). Learn More
```

I'm generating keys with the following:

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

From android release dir.
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my_app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Jar signer from release dir
`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk my_app`

Lastly zip align from release dir
`/Users/anonymous/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/zipalign -v 4 /Users/anonymous/project/my-app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk MyApp.apk`

I deleted the old keystore file so this is a new one.  I'm not sure how to resolve this on PlayStore.

I've searched but I can't find a solution that works for me.  I'm not sure what to do about the mismatched keystore file, assuming that's the issue and from my research it sounds like that's the issue...I'm using a different keystore file.  I've searched for a way to reset the key in Playstore to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the keystore to your new keystore for you manualy as there is no way to do this in the console.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.