# Google App Signing - Still able to upload the Apk signed with old Keystore

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I was signing my APK with a p12 certificate before opting-in to "Google Play App Signing"

I have followed the steps described in the Post below written by @MatPag to activate Google App Signing.

> [How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)

After activation, I can still sign and upload my APK file with both old p12 certificate and with the newly created Upload Keystore. Is this an expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

As far as I understand from Google Play App Signing documents, I should not be able to upload the APK to Google Play Console which has been signed with the old p12 certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. This allows developers to upload an App Bundle signed with the upload key and test it on a testing track while not changing their build or release process for APKs in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal behaviour. You can actually convert your p12 certificate to a keystore if you wish:

First create an empty keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias <somename> -keystore <somecertificatename>.jks
```

Now convert p12 certificate to a keystore:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore <yourp12certficate>.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore <somecertificatename>.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Google:

> Thanks for your patience.
>
> I have looked into your APK and screenshots you have provided and it seems there are no issues with this.
>
> You can continue to use both keys going forward to sign your app.
>
> **Case 1:** Sign APK with old p12 certificate which has been used before enrolling to Google App Signing.
>
> **Case 2:** Sign APK with newly created upload certificate which has been generated while enrolling to Google App Signing.