# Send a notification to a published android app

Tags: java, android

I have lost my keystore for my published app and I didn't add Firebase to it. I contacted the support they said I need to publish a new app with a different package name.

So, I need a way to send a notification to all users to install the new app (without FCM of course).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple answer:**

You cannot :) If you had your keystore key, then you could setup FCM and use it for sending messages to your users, sadly you do not have it setup and without a key it will not be possible anymore.

**Suggestion:**

For this to not happen again, store your keystore into Google Play Console App Signing section, and [this is how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103025/9188735).

---

Good luck :)

Comment: I am going to do this, Thanks :)