# PEPK Tool download, where from?

Tags: java, android

All I see is download that tool, where is it? I signed using generate app bundle and used my Keystore ( which i used in past to sign for my APK). i ticked export encrypted key and got a  PEPK file(private key .PEPK). i would like to know whats next? where do i download this PEPK tool from? when i upload on store it tells me To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in Google Play App Signing.....

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)