# How to find correct MD5 Key Hash of apk

Tags: android, md5

I'm trying to get the fingerprint of app, but the value obtained with android key tool is not the same as the value of some ready-made exe.(ex : "HashMyFiles", "Hashtab")

```html
android keytool : 9B:D8:DD:1.......
HashMyFiles , Hashtab : 52725F4.................
```

Can someone explain why this is? And I think what I need is the one that I got from the ready-made exe. How do I write my code?

Comment: What was the original apk signed with? Was it signed with a separate tool or Android Studio?

Comment: I'm not very sure but I think is Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you have signed it with Android Studio, you can read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode).

If its an app you've already published you can get its signature fingerprint from your Google Play Console as given by me in an earlier separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080245/2119723).

If its someone else's apk, you might want to ask them for those singing fingerprints for SHA1, SHA256 and MD5. There is no other way of retrieving the signing keys.

**How Google Play App Singing works**

1. You digitally sign each release using your upload key before
   publishing it to a track in the Play Console.
2. Google Play uses the upload certificate to verify your identity and then re-signs your release using the app signing key for distribution.
3. Each Android device checks the release’s app signing certificate matches the
   certificate of the installed app before updating it.

More about app signing [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

Comment: This apk is mine.I did this function is to prevent cheating, but I found that SHA1, SHA256 and MD5 does not change with the code change, so how to verify?

Comment: I've updated my answer. There are two signing keys in use when an app is published. One is your key to upload the other is google play's generated key.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate fingerprint is a short and unique representation of a certificate that is often requested by API providers alongside the package name to register an app to use their service.

The tool(HashMyFiles) that you use will provide you with a hash value of the Application and not the MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 fingerprint.so you should use the android keytool to get the fingerprint certificate for your app, also remember each build variant of your app can have different fingerprint and it is important to have a separate fingerprint for your release build.

If you want to know more go to :[Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Comment: I did this function to prevent cheating, but I found that the fingerprint does not change with the code change, so how to verify?