# Is it mandatory to upload aab(Android App Bundle) instead of APK file

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, android-app-bundle, cordova-android

In the recent try for uploading a new version of apk for existing application to PlayStore, threw an warning message as mentioned below

[image]

1. So the question is, is it mandatory to upload only aab files to PlayStore or normal apk file can also be updated.
2. If aab file has to be uploaded, then how to sign the aab file before uploading.

I referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing) for **Goolge App signing**. Is this also required ?

**Note:**

The application developed is a **cordova application**. So if the above mentioned things are mandatory is the procedure different to build for cordova application ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer (June 2023)**
AAB is mandatory when updating/uploading apps in Playstore.

> Google Play will start requiring new apps to be published with the
> Android App Bundle starting August 2021. This will replace the APK as
> the standard publishing format.

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html

**Update: As of 2023, the answer below is obsolete.**

> 1. So the question is, is it mandatory to upload only aab files to PlayStore or normal apk file can also be updated

Normal APK can also be uploaded / updated. This is just a warning and not an error message. Google Play will still allow you to continue

> 2. If aab file has to be uploaded, then how to sign the aab file before
>    uploading.

In Android Studio, when building signed APK / AAB, it will ask you to export an encrypted key. Take note of the location because you will use this exported key when you upload your AAB. See highlighted in yellow [image]

> I referred this Link for Goolge App signing. Is this also required ?

Nope, it's optional. Quoting Google Play Support:
*Using app signing by Google Play is optional. You can still upload an APK and manage your own keys instead of using an app bundle. However, if you lose your keystore or it becomes compromised, you won’t be able to update your app without publishing a new app with a new package name.* https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: is there a problem uploading aab ON the current apk? Do you think users faces any problem getting the update?

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Apps must now be uploaded as .aab bundles.

Comment: Can you give us a link/reference about the june-2023 date? I didn't find anything about this...

Answer (score 6):

> *"**Important**: In the second half of 2021, new apps will be required to
> publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger
> than 150 MB must use either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset
> Delivery".*

Taken from

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle