# How to upload Android App Bundles (.aab) on playstore for already published App

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, android-app-signing

I have already published my app on the playstore with keytore as .apk I am used to. But because of google notice that publishing App as APK will be obsolete in few months to come.

So, in a new upgrade of my app, I wish to upload it as app bundle. So while generating signed App bundle, with my app's keytore, I discovered that it generated the app bundle as (app-release.aab) and exported another key as private_key.pepk So when i revisited playstore console to upload the signed app bundle, I didn't see where to upload private_key.pepk.
So, I became worried. Not knowing what to do. I don't want to make a costly mistake. That is why I'm here for you to give me step by step method on how to continue from where I stopped.
Thanks for helping me..

**EDIT:**
I clicked create new release and then I clicked on opt in but didn't know which option to choose and proceed
Opt in to Play App Signing

Export and upload a key from Android Studio

Export and upload a key from Java keystore

Export and upload a key (not using Java Keystore)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing? I made it long ago and forgot details.

Comment: Thanks. The only challenge I have now is how to proceed. Google updated their play console. Your description is not same as what we have currently on the play console. I clicked create new release and then I clicked on opt in but didn't know which option to choose and proceed

Comment: Could you, please, add screenshots?

Comment: Yes Sir. I have added the screenshots now. Thank you

Comment: Last answer from that topic seems to be answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787059/2914140.

Comment: Click the first option "Export and upload a key from Android Studio" then upload the private_key.pepk.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your prompt guide

Comment: After I have uploaded the private key, How do I upload the Android studio signed APK?