# Android app - How to enable Google Play App Signing for existing app

Tags: android

I have a very old app that I would like to update on Google Play store.
I need to enroll Google app signing.
I have the old keystore key, allias and password.

I followed the very good tuto [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing#answer-44103025) but it is very old and some things need to be updated.

There is no more GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY but now it is a public key so can you help me to create my private key
`java -jar PATH_TO_PEPK --keystore=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE --alias=ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK --output=PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE --encryptionkey=GOOGLE_ENCRYPTION_KEY`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkk7p.png)

I have tried
`java -jar PATH_TO_PEPK --keystore=PATH_TO_KEYSTORE --alias=ALIAS_YOU_USE_TO_SIGN_APK --output=PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE --encryptionkey=PATH_TO_MY_PUBLIC_KEY`

but it is not working